# Sending tracking http requests

Tags: vast

I am trying to take advantage of the tracking features supplied by vast.  On each quartile I am sending an AJAX request (I have tried get, head, and post) to the url provided within VAST XML but every time I get 405'd.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide one of the quartile URLs so we can trace it? 
What happens when you call that quartile directly in the browser, does it work outside of your Ajax call?
Are your other events working fine? such as impression, start play, click, etc..

From the HTTP methods you tried GET should work, but  POST  should not be used with the VAST trackers. Hopefully the server you are hitting is not giving you an incorrect error code, masking an internal error.

Comment: Thanks for responding...the first quartile URL is:
http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/conversion/?ai=BnncM_kLMUcSxB7DU0AGDvoFYhbvPtQUAAAAQASDNit0eOABQ4_72yv7_____AViVoanGeGD92JOB6AO6AQs2NDB4MzYwX3htbMgBBakCrexD3LEJsD7AAgLgAgDqAhYvMTM4MTcwNjkvc25hcHN1X1ZpZGVv-AKC0h6AAwGQA-ADmAPgA6gDAeAEAaAGIw&sigh=NJIKkOO_w2k&label=videoplaytime25

You may be able to infer that I am using DFP.  When I paste the URL into my address bar it goes through fine and returns a 200 code.

Comment: Impressions are being counted as I get the XML file.  Start Play is the same thing.  All AJAX calls are getting 405'd for some bizarre reason.

Comment: OK, so I was (of course) running into the same origin policy problem.  With DFP the VAST tracking URL is a 1X1 gif.  All I had to do was create new Image()s and assign the src to submit the tracking URLs.  Thanks Gabriel for making me think about what I was doing.

Comment: Right, I do thinks there are some issues when calling from Ajax and you may have to provide a crossdomain.xml. Read up on CORS as well.

Comment: Gabriel, why POST should not be used with the VAST trackers? I haven't found any restrictions in http://www.iab.net/media/file/VASTv3.0.pdf